# How many ways can team $X$ win a hockey series in which teams $X$ and $Y$ play until a team wins $10$ matches?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In a hockey series between $X$ and $Y$, they decide to play until a team wins $10$ matches. What is the number of ways in which team $X$ wins?

My attempt (from the comments):

$9C0 + 10C1 + 11C2......... +19C9$ ...last match must be won by X right?

Comment: Please share what you have tried. This isn't a place to copy & paste your homework without any effort.

Comment: I tried hard bro....I'm trying it from past 2 days

Comment: Yes, but what have you tried?

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed if you don't share your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: 9C0 + 10C1 + 11C2......... +19C9.....last match must be won by X right?

Comment: Have  another think about the last term & look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity

Answer (score 3):

For team $X$ to win the tournament in $k$ matches, it must win $9$ of the first $k - 1$ matches and then win the $k$th match.  Notice that $k \leq 19$, for otherwise team $Y$ wins the tournament.  Hence, the number of ways $X$ can win is 
$$\binom{9}{9} + \binom{10}{9} + \binom{11}{9} + \ldots + \binom{18}{9} = \binom{19}{10}$$
by the [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).  Notice that the answer is the number of ways team $X$ can win $10$ of the first $19$ matches.